How to check if my vb.net project has dependency for -Visual C++ Redistributable Package 12 (2013)?
I have been asked to check if the  Visual C++ Redistributable Package 12 (2013) can be safely removed and if it does not have any impact.. I need to figure out  if the application has dependency for VC++ redistributable package? Can anyone suggest basic checks that can be done to ensure its not needed?
I tried searching the code base and various references of the project  but could not find any such dependency for VC++. I need to know if this is really needed for my application to function correctlly before trying to proceed with uninstalling the components.

Why? This is a small package, and the saving is unlikely to be worth the effort. And you need to test all applications exhaustively to show that it's never needed. E.g. if there's a PDF generator in your web app, you might not notice the dependency until you try to generate a PDF.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
